# Continuity of difficult vector function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a question about the continuity of a vector function. I have proved sufficiency for a function to be continuous but I am wondering if this is also a necessity.

Assume $f(t,z(t))$, is a funtion into $\mathbb{R}$. Also assume that $z=z(t)$ is a real vector with $n$ components.

I am able to show that if $f(t,V)$ is continuous in respect to $t$ when $V$ is constant. And if $f(t,V)$ is continuous with respect to $V$ when $t$ is constant ($V$ is a vector). And also if every component of $z(t)$ is continious with respect to $t$, then the function $f(t,z(t))=G(t)$ is continious with respect to $t$. Do you guys agree that this is correct?

Also, if what Iwrote above is correct it shows 3 conditions that are sufficient for $f(t,z(t))$ to be continious with respect to $t$. But can we show that these conditions also are necessary? I am not able to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is not true in general. The function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ is continuous with respect to each coordinate, but it is not continuous, since $f(t,t)=1/2$ for all $t\neq 0$. If we take $z(t)=t\sin(1/t)$ for $t\neq 0$ and $z(0)=0$, then $t\mapsto f(t,z(t))$ is not continuous.

Comment: Thank you, I think I made a mistake in my proof. After using the proof with your exampleI see that I make a logical mistake. Thanks for your help!